# Using Vim I Can read files in NFS Mount directory, but cannot modify the files?

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, vim, nfs

Given that:

- I’m running as **root** in my local computer.
- I have a NFS mounted directory called “server_views” in my local computer.
- This is how the “server_views” directory is configured in fstab and mstab in my local computer:

  /etc/fstab

  ```
      server:/server_views /server_views nfs rw,defaults,noauto,users,suid,exec,tcp,posix,soft 0 0
  ```

  /etc/mstab

  ```
      server:/server_views /server_views nfs rw,users,nodev,tcp,posix,soft,vers=4,addr=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,clientaddr=YYY.YY.YY.Y 0 0
  ```
- I have a file called “foo.c” inside the “server_views” directory in the server.

**In my local computer; While inside the mounted directory("server_views"):**

Running ls –l inside mounted “server_views” directory outputs:

```
  -r-xr-xr-x 1 nobody nobody 28668 Mar  2  2017   foo.c
```

*If I try to write to the "foo.c" file with Vim;  I get the following error in the Vim console:

```
"foo.c" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

*If I try to change foo.c permissions I get:

```
chmod: changing permissions of `foo.c': Operation not permitted
```

**If I manually copy the “foo.c” file to some unmounted directory in my local computer:**

Running ls –l  inside directory containing foo.c in my local computer gives:

```
-r-xr-xr-x 1 17932   26 28720 Mar 22 17:58  foo.c
```

I can write foo.c without issues using Vim.

Does anyone know why I cannot write to file “foo.c” while I’m inside the mounted NFS directory “server_views”, but then can write to the same file “foo.c” if the file is manually copied into my local computer to a non mounted directory?

Comment: The root user on your machine is probably mapped to a non-root user on the server (possibly `nobody`).

Answer (score 3):

This is typically controlled by the `root_squash` setting on the NFS server which prevents `root` on the client from being `root` on the NFS server (which is usually a very good security practice). `root_squash` is the default, so typically one would only see `no_root_squash` if someone for some reason needed to disable the squash on the remote `root` user. In `/etc/exports` on the NFS server for example

```
/somedir dangerhost(rw,no_root_squash,async) \
         otherhost(rw,async) \
         ...
```

This can be tested for with a `1777` mode directory which will allow any remote user to write to that directory:

```
nfsserver# mkdir /somedir/tmp ; chmod 1777 /somedir/tmp
```

And then on a client assuming `/somedir` is mounted at `/mnt`

```
$ touch /mnt/tmp/foo
$ sudo touch /mnt/tmp/bar
$ ls -l /mnt/tmp/{foo,bar}
-rw-r--r-- 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody 0 Apr 15 14:27 /mnt/tmp/bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 jhqdoe    jhqdoe    0 Apr 15 14:27 /mnt/tmp/foo
$
```

Here `root` has been squashed to the `nfsnobody` user (this may on other platforms be `nobody` or other accounts).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in a gate computer(The IP Masquerade configuration was incorrect) that was between my local computer and the NFS server.

The gate computer was rebooted, the eth interfaces were brought up(using ifup) and the firewall was restarted (The gate had rc.firewall-2.4)

This served as a good reference: 
http://en.tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/